# Too much issues compilling kivyMD apps to APK

Tags: kivymd

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDScreen:

```
MDLabel:
    id: lab    
    text: "WELLCOME"
    bold:'True'
    font_size: 40
    halign: 'center'
    color:1,0,1,1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .83}        

MDFillRoundFlatButton:
    text: "language-python"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    size_hint: (0.25,0.08)
    on_release: app.kav()
```

'''

class Example(MDApp):
def build(self):
self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
return Builder.load_string(KV)

```
def kav(self):
    self.root.ids.lab.text = 'Have A Great Day'
```

Example().run()

i even tried this little app. it still doesnt work.???

Answer (score 0):

It`s work

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = ''' 
MDScreen:

    MDLabel:
        id: lab    
        text: "WELLCOME"
        bold:'True'
        font_size: 40
        halign: 'center'
        color:1,0,1,1
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .83}        
    
    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "language-python"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        size_hint: (0.25,0.08)
        on_release: app.kav()
'''

class Example(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def kav(self):
        self.root.ids.lab.text = 'Have A Great Day'


Example().run()
```

Comment: Thanks... How can i use  Android studio to convert   kivyapp  to aab?

Comment: Use buildozer. command "buildozer -v android release" automatikly create aab

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).